# How to find the Registration page

Tags: plugins, user-registration

I am managing the WordPress website i don't have the document of the website my problem is the website has the registration page please see [this link]

but when i check the registration page in WordPress admin the page is blank i don't have any idea how the previous developer linked the page can anyone help where to find the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `buddypress` page, linked with the page ID 4275. The body class of your delivered HTML is:

```
<body class="registration register  buddypress page page-id-4275 page-template-default admin-bar no-customize-support no-js">
```

To edit this page itself, go to http://hoteliersnetworkme.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=4275&action=edit

BuddyPress filters the content of this page and adds a registration form.

To modify the registration form itself, please refer to the [BuddyPress documentation](https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/guides/modifying-the-registration-form/).

*BTW: Seems like you have got a lot of work to do, cleaning all this up. Just at glancing at it I found 36 stylesheets and 61 Javascript files, as well as inline scripts, from at least 22 plugins plus your theme and child theme..*

Comment: How can edit and read the code for buddypress can u explain so it would really helpful for me

Comment: I do not know exactly, but it seems pretty clear in the BuddyPress documentation. Please look there, and remember that this site does not support third party questions - if you have any further questions to BuddyPress, refer to their support forum :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably under your theme folder. Maybe a custom page-template, something like `page-register.php` or similar.

> but when i check the registration page in WordPress admin the page is blank

Check the right side, is there a "template" applied?

edit: hearing this is a buddypress theme I'd look into `themes\[yourtheme]\buddypress\members\register.php` or similar paths

Answer (score 0):

When I looked that that page source code there was a class name of page-template-default which would indicate that it is using a standard default file, eg index.php, page.php etc.